# Changing the font of colorkey labels with draw.colorkey

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following sample code:

```
require(latticeExtra)
require(gridExtra)
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)


lay <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2), 1,4,byrow = FALSE)

z<-sort(rnorm(100))
x<- rep(seq(1,10), times=10)
y<-rep(seq(1,10), each=10)
p<- levelplot(z ~ x * y,
          par.settings=list(axis.text=list(fontfamily="serif"),),
          colorkey = list(labels=list(par.settings=list(fontfamily='serif'))))

leg.list <- p$legend$right$args$key
leg <-  draw.colorkey(leg.list)
grid.arrange(grobs = list(p, leg), layout_matrix = lay)
```

When I run this code I get the following image:
[image: output of above code]

I would like the font of the labels in the little colorkey (part of the levelplot) to match the font of the labels in the large colorkey (made using `draw.colorkey()`). How can I do this?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
leg <-  draw.colorkey(leg.list)
leg$children[[4]]$children[[1]]$gp$cex <- 0.75
grid.arrange(grobs = list(p, leg), layout_matrix = lay)
```

[image]

Setting the same font family for the two colorkeys, we get a better result:

```
leg <-  draw.colorkey(leg.list)
leg$children[[4]]$children[[1]]$gp$cex <- 0.8
leg$children[[4]]$children[[1]]$gp$fontfamily <- "serif"
grid.arrange(grobs = list(p, leg), layout_matrix = lay)
```

[image]